# Skipping some css files in HTML Master page (.net): is it possible?

Tags: javascript, html, .net, css

I have a site where 6 css files are linked, But in a page i need to use only 3 css files. My developers are using master page in .net, so they don't want to change that. So, my question is: Is there any way I can skip few css files which is linked?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Another solution (doesn't need jQuery) is adding a configuration property to the master page like this:

Site.Master.cs

```
private bool _IncludeOtherCss = true;
public bool IncludeOtherCss {
 get { return _IncludeOtherCss; }
 set { _IncludeOtherCss = value; } 
}
```

Site.Master (head section)

```
<%if (IncludeOtherCss)
  { %>
    <link href="~/Styles/Site.css" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" />
  <%} %>
```

Other page:

```
 protected void Page_Init(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            (Master as SiteMaster).IncludeOtherCss = false;
        }
```

Answer (score 3):

It is not very 'elegant' but you can use a jQuery script to manipulate and remove the link:

```
<script type="text/javascript">
        $(document).ready(function () {
           $("link[type='text/css']").remove();
        });
    </script>
```

You can use jQuery selector to refine the search. I.e.

```
 $("link[href='Styles/Site.css']").remove();
```

Comment: I added another answer (more elegant and without jQuery)